# Does water negate falling damage?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island Riptide, water features more prominently than in the original Dead Island. Some buildings are close enough to water that you may jump from their roofs to water below.

If I jump and land in water from a height that would normally cause me to take falling damage, would landing in water negate it? Does the height of the water matter?

There are essentially three heights: shallow, deep, and over-the-head level. Shallow allows you to run in it, but slows you down. Deep doesn't allow you to run. Over-the-head means your vision is submerged and you begin to drown not crouching.

Comment: Seems like is is a question that you could figure out quite easily by just trying it out. Does this game not have game saves or a "you died doing something silly" respawn type mechanic?

Comment: There is a respawn mechanism. You respawn at a checkpoint and lose %15 of your money. However, there is a glitch in the game where you can side-hop or back-hop (special movement maneuvers) in mid-air, which negates falling damage. So, I've never let myself land in water without trying to negate falling damage that way. The situation is just rare enough that I forget to test it.

Comment: I see, well hopefully someone will come along soon enough that will know. Best of luck.